# How to use parameter 2 in a for loop nested in Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, pdf

I could not use the second parameter(`%%b`) in the first for loop to compare (`if !count! GTR %%b`) in the for second loop, hoping the experts to help, sorry about my English is not good.

File `text1.txt`

```
    #       #
#Employee*.PDF,3
School*.PDF,4
Family*.PDF,5
```

Folder `c:\user\text`

```
xxxxxxxxx.pdf
Employee1.pdf
Employee3.pdf
Employee2.pdf
Employee4.pdf
Employee5.pdf
Employee6.pdf
Employee7.pdf
School1.pdf
School3.pdf
School2.pdf
School4.pdf
School5.pdf
School6.pdf
School7.pdf
```

Total Code:

```
@Echo off
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2 eol=#" %%a in ('Type text1.txt') do (
    set /a count=0
    for /f %%x in ('dir C:\user\text\%%a /b') do (
        set /a count+=1
        if !count! GTR %%b ( 
            del "C:\user\text\%%x"
        )
    )
)
```

I cannot use `%%b` in the second for loop.
output after run `All files are deleted`.

but i just want to delete :

```
Employee4.pdf
Employee5.pdf
Employee6.pdf
Employee7.pdf
School5.pdf
School6.pdf
School7.pdf
```

Help me, please!

I tried... add `set /a flag=%%b` and change Comparative conditions = `if !count! GTR !flag!`

```
 for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2 eol=#" %%a in ('Type text1.txt') do (
     set /a count=0
     set /a flag=%%b
     for /f %%x in ('dir C:\user\text\%%a /b') do (
         set /a count+=1
         if !count! GTR !flag! ( 
             del "C:\user\text\%%x"
         )
    )
)
```

But output `!flag! = 5`, 
equal to its final value `Family*.PDF,5`.

Comment: I am not 100% with you here. Do you want to match if the files within the content of `text1.txt` exists in `C:\user\text`?

Comment: I'm sorry, 
I posted the wrong file text1.txt, I edited it above

Comment: ok, let me have a look quick. So you just want the file with the highest number?

Comment: yes, I just want to get files with  `!count! > %% b`

Comment: ok, but `2.pdf` is also bigger than `1.pdf` so you want that as well?

Comment: yes, My problem is to use the condition in the `text1.txt` file and display the files in the `C:\user\text` folder, as in the example above I just need to get the `Emloyee4.pdf` file in the `C:\user\text` folder after running the condition in the `text1.txt` file is `Employee * .PDF, 3`.

Comment: Ok, but why do you then have to work off the list in a file then? This can be done without a file..

Comment: I was asked to use the .bat file to open the file `text1.txt` and then search in the directory of eligible files then `del` it, not just `echo` it as in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code seems to work fine (I added some code to add demo files and a minor change in the `dir` command to match environment - adapt to your needs):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM create test environment:
for /l %%a in (1,1,7) do break>School%%a.pdf
for /l %%a in (1,1,7) do break>Family%%a.pdf
dir /b *.pdf
echo ---------
type text1.txt
echo ---------
pause


for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2 eol=#" %%a in ('Type text1.txt') do (
    set /a count=0
    for /f %%x in ('dir %~dp0%%a /b') do (
        set /a count+=1
        if !count! GEQ %%b echo "%%~fx"
    )
)
```

Output:

```
Family1.pdf
Family2.pdf
Family3.pdf
Family4.pdf
Family5.pdf
Family6.pdf
Family7.pdf
School1.pdf
School2.pdf
School3.pdf
School4.pdf
School5.pdf
School6.pdf
School7.pdf
---------
#       #
#Employee*.PDF,3
School*.PDF,4
Family*.PDF,5
---------
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . . 
"D:\tmp\test\School4.pdf"
"D:\tmp\test\School5.pdf"
"D:\tmp\test\School6.pdf"
"D:\tmp\test\School7.pdf"
"D:\tmp\test\Family5.pdf"
"D:\tmp\test\Family6.pdf"
"D:\tmp\test\Family7.pdf"
```

Oh yes - and I changed `GTR` to `GEQ` to match your example.

Comment: If I want to `delete` the file in a condition that does not `echo`, what should I do?

Comment: What do you want to delete? `...1.pdf` .. `...3.pdf` or `...4.pdf` .. `...x.pdf`?

Comment: how about substituting the `echo` command with the `del` command then?

Comment: Instead of `echo` like before, I want to `delete` the files in the root directory.

Comment: then remove `echo` and type in `del /Q`

Comment: Thanks to all the bro, for helping me

Answer (score 1):

The dir command needs a wildcard following `%%a`

```
for /f %%x in ('dir /b "C:\user\text\%%a*"') do (
```

Also `%%b` read from `text1.txt` isn't just the number, but has the extension `.pdf` attached.

Either use

- `if !count! GTR %%~nb` to strip off the extension, or
- modify `test1.txt` to have another comma between the number and the extension.

Comment: I tried editing it to `if !count! GTR %%~nb` but still not successful and `test1.txt` is fixed

Comment: Constantly changing the information in question doesn't help to find a solution for **your** question but frustrates respondents.

Comment: I will draw experience, thank you for your suggestions